# Actually realistic driving simulator

Tags: game, simulation

I just started driving, and I wanted to use a driving simulator to get some practice with turning at the right time, how much I should turn the steering wheel, knowing which way to turn the steering when I'm in reverse, parallel parking, etc.

I tried a few free driving simulators on the App Store and online, and the controls are too much like Mario Kart and don't seem that similar to an actual car.

Requirements:

- steering wheel rather than left/right buttons, and one that turns the wheel only slightly, just like an actual car
- transmission shifter, with at least a reverse mode and drive mode. (Most simulators seem to have the break pedal double as a reverse, which is something I don't want.)
- in drive and reverse modes, the car should cruise forward/backward, so you need to hold the break to keep the car from moving.
- first-person perspective

Desired features:

- turn signals
- rewind a few seconds so that I can get a do-over for any mistakes
- sub-$10 or ideally free/gratis
- Android, iOS, or Windows (although I would be curious about any Mac apps too)

Comment: I've consulted some driving instructors and was told that no such program can actually teach you to drive properly in the context you mentioned. It can train you to read the road signs and follow the rules, but not turn the steering wheel by a proper amount and at the right time (it differes from car to car in real life). For example, cheap Russian cars typically require you to turn it more and it takes more force to do it, while modern European cars take just a bit of turning and it can be done while barely using your fingers. So, for safery reasons, don't let games teach you to drive.

Comment: Wow, there's that much variation between different cars? That sucks...

Comment: I don't want to recommend software for training physical things but if you want some enjoy you might try PS game Gran Turismo.